# NHibernate Where in with a User Type

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, queryover

I'm having a lot of trouble getting nHibernate to do a where in clause on a field that is mapped with an IUserType implementation. All of the types below are simplified for the question.

I have a table that looks something like this :

```
int id
nvarchar notPartOfUserType
nvarchar partOfUserType1
nvarchar partOfUserType2
nvarchar partOfUserType3
...
```

this is mapped to an object

```
int Id
string NotUserType
UserType UserType
...
```

and UserType looks something like

```
string Part1
string Part2
string Part3
...
```

partOfUserType1, partOfUserType2 and partOfUserType3 are mapped to come out of the db into a UserType by implementing IUserType in UserTypeMapping. Here's the NullSafeGet for that class. It's not that complex.

```
        public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var field1 = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]) as string;
        var field2 = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[1]) as string;
        var field3 = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[2]) as string;

        return new UserType
        {
            Part1 = field1
            Part2 = field2,
            Part3 = field3
        };
    }
```

And that's mapped by code. Here's an excerpt for that property

```
        Property(p => p.UserType, map =>
        {
            map.Columns(m => m.Part1("partOfUserType1"), m => m.Part2("partOfUserType2"), m => m.Part3("partOfUserType3"));
            map.Type<UserTypeMapping>();
        });
```

All of my regular gets and saves/updates work fine. I can also do a Where In clause on fields not part of UserType just fine by:

```
var list = new List<string> {"123", "456"};
var result = session.Query<MyType>().Where(row => list.Contains(row.NotUserType)).ToList();
```

But, the problem: I want to do a where in clause on the partOfUserType1 field. I can't for the life of me get that to work. I've tried every way I can think of using the Linq provider and the QueryOver syntax. No dice.

Is this possible?

### EDIT - SOLUTION

Thanks to Oskar Berggren for leading me to this answer.
I should have been using a component map rather than a user type in this case.

Before

```
Property(p => p.UserType, map =>
{
    map.Columns(m => m.Part1("partOfUserType1"), m => m.Part2("partOfUserType2"), m => m.Part3("partOfUserType3"));
    map.Type<UserTypeMapping>();
});
```

After

```
Component(c => c.UserType, component =>
{
    component.Property(p => p.Part1, map => map.Column("partOfUserType1"));
    component.Property(p => p.Part2, map => map.Column("partOfUserType2"));
    component.Property(p => p.Part3, map => map.Column("partOfUserType3"));
});
```

Of course my actual type are much more complicated, requiring a user type within the component mapping. But this works well now.

Comment: Did you try `list.Contains(row.NotUserType.Part1)`?

Comment: Sorry, while renaming everything more generically for the question, I must have gotten rid of the property in that statement. Yeah, I've tried 'list.Contains(row.UserType.Part1)'. nHibernate throws from deep within 'could not resolve property: Part1 of: MyType'. Which is weird, since Part1 is a property of MyType, but of MyType.UserType. I'm starting to think nHibernate can't do a Where In clause with an IUserType at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query on parts of the usertype, I think you want to look at using Component mapping instead of a user type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of component mapping. Worked beautifully. Now I just have to re-implement all of the explicit sql I had done to work around the issue. I updated the question with the solution.